# basic python indentation/dedentation question

Tags: python, syntax, indentation

Why does the following code produce indentation error in the Python console (version 2.6.5 in my case)? I was convinced the following was a valid piece of code:

```
if True:
    print '1'
print 'indentation error on this line'
```

If I insert a blank line between the if-block and the last print, the error goes away:

```
if True:
    print '1'

print 'no error here'
```

I am little bit puzzled, from the documentation it seems to me that blank (or only-white-space) lines should not make any difference. Any hints?

Comment: Try the first code snippet again (copy and paste it from your question).  It doesn't give an error.

Comment: Ah, did you do this in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: @Sven Marnach: in the console, yes, it does.  The second print is "..." indented, as it's still autoindenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the usage of the Python console, not the Python language. If you put everything in a method, it works.

Example:

```
>>> if True:
...     print '1'
... print 'indentation error on this line'
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print 'indentation error on this line'
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def test():
...     if True:
...         print '1'
...     print 'no indentation error on this line'
... 
>>> test()
1
no indentation error on this line
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what i needed. The motivation for the question was a behavior of one Python IDE where this causes interactive work troublesome. Thanks to your explanation now i know how to fill in the bug report:)

Answer (score 5):

The console accepts a single instruction (multiple lines if it's a definition of a `function`; `if`, `for`, `while`, ...) to execute at a time.

Here: 2 instructions

```
                                          _______________
if True:                                # instruction 1  |
    print '1'                           # _______________|
print 'indentation error on this line'  # instruction 2  |
                                          ----------------
```

Here: 2 instructions separated by a blanck line; ***A blanck line is like when you hit enter*** => A single instruction by execution

```
if True:
    print '1'         # instruction 1
[enter]
print 'no error here' # instruction 1
```